# Creating an AWS EC2 instance through python boto3 script on Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

Below is my code to launch an instance on custom VPC but i am seeing below error. Need your assistance in finding the problem:

---

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     session_client=boto3.client(service_name='ec2')
     response = session_client.run_instances(
     #SecurityGroupIds=['sg-0ffb80bb93205a004'],
     #SubnetId='subnet-0bb30254459fd4714',
     MaxCount=1,
     MinCount=1,
     NetworkInterfaces=[
        {
            'NetworkInterfaceId':'eni-0846a5c0c47e98b3c',
            'Description': 'Network Interface Description',
            'DeviceIndex': 123,
            'SubnetId': 'subnet-0bb30254459fd4714'
        },
    ],
     LaunchTemplate={
     'LaunchTemplateId': 'lt-0d3c7dd295796ad6b',
     'Version': '1'
      })
```

---

```
Error: Network interfaces and an instance-level subnet ID may not be specified on the same request",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
```

Thanks,
Bapu Reddy Battu

Answer (score 0):

There are two subnetid parameters that can be passed while creating an EC2 instance through boto3

**1) SubnetId at root level in the request :**

> **SubnetId** (string) -- [EC2-VPC] The ID of the subnet to launch the
>   instance into. If you specify a network interface, you must specify
>   any subnets as part of the network interface.

Since you are passing the NetworkInterfaces parameter, this SubnetId will not be passed.

**2) SubnetId as part of NetworkInterfaces parameter**

> **SubnetId** (string) -- The ID of the subnet associated with the network
>   interface. Applies only if creating a network interface when launching
>   an instance.

Since you are using an already existing network interface. You should not pass the SubnetId parameter inside NetworkInterfaces either.

Reference documentation : [EC2 run instances - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)